# Can a display landline phone instrument be made to work without a separate electrical connection

Tags: power-supply, telephone

Since phone lines can supply power, there are landline phone instruments which work without a separate electrical connection. Typically these have no display etc.

There are also those instruments which require an electrical connection. I imagine that it would be possible to design these instruments in such a way that when they are connected to the phone line but not to an electrical line separately, they should atleast work like a basic phone instrument without the display and other features which require the additional power. However none of them seem to do so.

Anyway, my question is about this particular model from AT&T - model 1187 - http://www.manualslib.com/manual/10649/AtAndt-1187.html#manual

Is there a way to modify the phone such that it can work without an electrical connection all the time. I am not interested in the display or speaker phone or any other features. Is there any simple change I can do to the instrument easily to make it work without the power cord being connected?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems with your assumptions in the first two paragraphs. I can't think of a technical reason phones couldn't be designed to provide basic functionality in the case of power loss. It would save having a seperate phone for emergency use during power outages and I'd expect it wouldn't cost more than a few dollars extra to implement.

However modifying an existing phone is not likely to be practical. You'd be working 'blind' without a schematic and reverse-engineering high-volume designs that are likely to contain some custom / programmable chips without design information or source code is likely to be difficult.

I don't believe you'll find an easy solution for modifying one. Unlike a "simple" phone for example the DTMF (touch-tone) generation is likely connected to all the same circuitry that powers the other functions so trying to isolate the core functions from the more advanced without documentation would be tricky.

Comment: A few extra dollars per part, manufactured in the tens or hundreds of thousands of units, is a huge cost for such little benefit. No company would bother. +1 for a good explanation though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the DC voltage that is normally provided by the phone company; in Australia from memory it's -42V, and it's probably pretty similar worldwide.  Then, to get the phone to do things like ring, you need to supply various AC voltages as well.

Rather than doing these things yourself, its probably easiest to obtain a telephone line simulator (TLS); [for example](http://www.natcomm.com.au/au/telephone-line-simulators/); note that that company sell a TLS that can be configured to simulate the nominal line conditions of a wide range of countries; note also that they're not really what you'd call cheap.

Alternatively, you could google for some simple/cheap TLS circuits.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I want to connect the phone to the phone line.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

The phone in question is a cordless phone with loudspeaking facility. This means it's basic plain-ordinary-telephony circuit is likely to be built around a more powerful circuit that is capable of doing basic handset interfacing AND loudspeaking functions.

There are handsets around that can harvest enough energy from the line to make a decent attempt at loudspeaking but it's unlikely that this is one of them. Why should it - it naturally attracts a customer who wants to wander down the garden while using the phone and it MUST have external power to provide the rf link.

Comment: The phone comes with 2 instruments - a cordless one and a corded one. I was wondering about the corded one.

Comment: i was only referring to the base station part. It would not make technical or economic sense for the base station design to use standard line-powered telephony handset circuitry.